# Build error after updating to Android Studio 3.0 with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Today, Android Studio just release 3.0. After I updated all the dependencies, I cannot build my project even the IDE does not show any error in code. (Gradle Sync is fine.)

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.51"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (App)**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.1.2"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "build"

    productFlavors {
        UAT {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "UAT"
            dimension "build"
        }

        SIS {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "SIS"
            dimension "build"
        }

        PROD {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "PROD"
            dimension "build"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
    // Skip
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-rc1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
}
```

I have tried api, implementation and compile .

**Error**

```
e: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\project\app\src\main\java\com\example\ContextExtension.kt: (47, 34): Unresolved reference: LOLLIPOP
e: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\project\app\src\main\java\com\example\ContextExtension.kt: (104, 58): Unresolved reference: LOLLIPOP
e: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\project\app\src\main\java\com\example\ContextExtension.kt: (173, 58): Unresolved reference: LOLLIPOP
...
```

But the line it is fine before update, and Android Studio does not highlight it red.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
```

For your reference, the error shows up in `:app:compilePRODDebugKotlin`.

**Edit:** I have found the reason. I misunderstand `implementation` and left out an `exclude`. Adding back the exclude fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you try clean the project and rebuild it?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Yes, of course =)

Comment: @Joshua nice that you found a solution yourself. It might be worth to post your solution as an answer. Stackoverflow allows to post an answer to own questions :) It will make it more obvious for other devs.

Comment: @andrei_zaitcev It is just me stupidly think `implementation` can replace `exclude`. Converting just by replace `compile` with `implementation` should be fine in most of the cases.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Fair enough then to not post it as an answer.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic as "this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."